# Skewed grid in plot

Tags: plotting

Is is possible to add a skewed grid in a plot? Consider the following image;
[image]

The grey axes are the normal axes ($\mathbf{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{e}_2$), the black axes are transformations $\mathbf{e}'_1=2\mathbf{e}_1 - \mathbf{e}_2$ and $\mathbf{e}'_2=-\mathbf{e}_1 + \mathbf{e}_2$ and the blue arrow is $(1,1)$ in the $\mathbf{e}$-base and $(2,3)$ in the $\mathbf{e}'$-base. I would like to insert a (red) grid that is “aligned” with the $\mathbf{e}'$-base, i.e. skewed so that one clearly sees that the blue arrow has coordinates $(2,3)$ in the transformed coordinate system. TIA.

MWE:

```
o = {0, 0};
e1 = {1, 0};
e2 = {0, 1};
e1p = 2 e1 - e2;
e2p = -e1 + e2;
v = {1, 1};
a0 = Graphics[{Blue, Arrow[{o, v}]}, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 4.5}, {-3, 2}}, Frame -> True];
a1 = Graphics[{Black, Opacity[.25], Arrow[{o, e1}], Arrow[{o, e2}]}];
a2 = Graphics[{Black, Arrow[{o, e1p}], Arrow[{o, e2p}]}];
k1 = Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{o, 2 e1p}]}];
k2 = Graphics[{{Red, Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 3 e2p}]}, {Red, Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 1 e2p}]}, {Red, Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 2 e2p}]}}];
Show[a0, k1, k2, a1, a2]
```

The code might not be the best, improvements are most welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `ColorFunction -> (White &)`you can have a white background:

```
o = {0, 0};
e1 = {1, 0};
e2 = {0, 1};
e1p = 2 e1 - e2;
e2p = -e1 + e2;
v = {1, 1};
a0 = Graphics[{Blue, Arrow[{o, v}]}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 4.5}, {-3, 2}}, Frame -> True];
a1 = Graphics[{Black, Opacity[.25], Arrow[{o, e1}], Arrow[{o, e2}]}];
a2 = Graphics[{Black, Arrow[{o, e1p}], Arrow[{o, e2p}]}];
k1 = Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{o, 2 e1p}]}];
k2 = Graphics[{{Red, Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 3 e2p}]}, {Red, 
     Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 1 e2p}]}, {Red, 
     Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 2 e2p}]}}];
pl = ContourPlot[.2, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -3, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(e1p.{-#2, #1}) &, (e2p.{-#2, #1}) &}, 
   Mesh -> {Range[-5, 5], Range[-5, 5]}, ColorFunction -> (White &)];
Show[pl, a0, k1, k2, a1, a2]
```

[image]

With `ContourPlot[0.2,...,ColorFunction->Hue` you can have any color you want by changing `0.2`:

[image]

Using `MeshStyle`you can specify the display of mesh lines. E.g.

```
pl = ContourPlot[.2, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -3, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(e1p.{-#2, #1}) &, (e2p.{-#2, #1}) &}, 
   Mesh -> {Range[-5, 5], Range[-5, 5]}, ColorFunction -> (White &), 
   MeshStyle -> {{Magenta, Opacity[0.5]}, {Green, Opacity[0.5]}}];
Show[pl, a0, k1, k2, a1, a2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another way is shifting the infiniteline `InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, e1p]` and `InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, e2p]`

```
o = {0, 0};
e1 = {1, 0};
e2 = {0, 1};
e1p = 2 e1 - e2;
e2p = -e1 + e2;
v = {1, 1};
a0 = Graphics[{Blue, Arrow[{o, v}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 4.5}, {-3, 2}}, Frame -> True];
a1 = Graphics[{Black, Opacity[.25], Arrow[{o, e1}], Arrow[{o, e2}]}];
a2 = Graphics[{Black, Arrow[{o, e1p}], Arrow[{o, e2p}]}];
k1 = Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{o, 2 e1p}]}];
k2 = Graphics[{{Red, Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 3 e2p}]}, {Red, 
     Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 1 e2p}]}, {Red, 
     Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 2 e2p}]}}];
skew = Graphics[{Opacity[.5], 
    Table[{{Green, InfiniteLine[j*e2p, e1p]}, {Cyan, 
       InfiniteLine[j*e1p, e2p]}}, {j, -5, 5}]}];
Show[skew, a0, k1, k2, a1, a2, PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {-3, 2}}]
```

[image]

`ParametricPlot` also work.

```
skew2 = ParametricPlot[x*e1p + y*e2p, {x, -8, 8}, {y, -8, 8}, 
  Mesh -> {Range[-8, 8]}, PlotStyle -> White, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-2, 4}, {-3, 2}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Cyan, Green}]
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `e1p` and `e2p` to define two lists of transformation functions and use them to translate `InfiniteLine[{o, e2p}]` and `InfiniteLine[{o, e2p}]` to get the grid lines with desired slants.

```
trs1 = # e1p & /@ Range[-7, 7];
trs2 = # e2p & /@ Range[-7, 8];

Graphics[{{ 
   Sequence @@ CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "GraphicsGridLines"}],
   Translate[InfiniteLine[{o, e2p}], #] & /@ trs1,
   Translate[InfiniteLine[{o, e1p}], #] & /@ trs2},
  Black, Opacity[.25], Arrow[{o, e1}], Arrow[{o, e2}],
  Opacity[1], Arrow[{o, e1p}], Arrow[{o, e2p}],
  Blue, Arrow[{o, v}],
  Red, Arrow[{e1p, 2 e1p}],
  Arrowheads[{0, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}], 
  Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 3 e2p}]},
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-3, 2}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: A fine solution (as always!). The code is bit difficult for me to understand, but that is a fault on my side(!). Would it be possible to change the ticks/tick labels also so they agree with the skewed lines?

Comment: @mf67, please see the updated version. If  you want additional ticks on the left frame, try using `FrameTicks ->  {{Range[-3, 5, .5], Automatic},{ Automatic,  Automatic}}`.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but should not the 3 on the x-axis be 0 and 1 on the y-axis be 0 in the skewed system's tick labels?

Comment: @mf67, right,now i see what you mean. That's good new question.

Comment: Obviously there is a bug in `Translate` + `InfiniteLine`, because `Translate[InfiniteLine[{o, e2p}], trs1]` should wok too.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, good point. That's what I tried first, thinking `Translate`/``Scale` would would work without having to map.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, we can do this with graphics primitives. However, the lazy way is to use ContourPlot, only for the sake of the Mesh. Here is your example:

```
a1 = Graphics[{Black, Opacity[.25], Arrow[{o, e1}], Arrow[{o, e2}]}];
a2 = Graphics[{Black, Arrow[{o, e1p}], Arrow[{o, e2p}]}];
k1 = Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{o, 2 e1p}]}];
k2 = Graphics[{{Red, Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 3 e2p}]}, {Red, 
     Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 1 e2p}]}, {Red, 
     Arrow[{2 e1p, 2 e1p + 2 e2p}]}}];
pl = ContourPlot[1, {x, -2, 4}, {y, -3, 2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(e1p.{-#2, #1}) &, (e2p.{-#2, #1}) &}, 
   Mesh -> {Range[-5, 5], Range[-5, 5]}];
Show[{pl, a0, k1, k2, a1, a2}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to control the yellow "paper" color and the color of the mesh?